# Is there a way to retrieve the icon image of files and folders in macOS using SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, image, swiftui, icons, macos-catalina

I am working on building an app using SwiftUI in a MacOS version 10.15.7 and i need to display the icons of files/folders that are chosen by the user. Please refer to the screenshots to understand what icons I refer to here. Thank You.

[Icons to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjW1f.png):

[image: Icons to the left]

[Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xiq8w.png):

[image: Icons]

[Icons to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQSk0.png):

[image: Icons to the left]

Comment: You can find many of the system icons here `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources`  If this is not what you are asking, please refine your question.

Comment: This directory seems to contain all the required images. But, Is there a way to refer to the icon image in code by using anything like the URL or NSOpenPanel?

Comment: You can use `NSImage imageNamed` (sorry don't know swiftui so not sure of the exact syntax) There are many OS images using the type `NSImageName`.  See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimagename

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AppKit to get the NSImage and convert it to an Image

Image(nsImage: NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFile: "/Users/stephan/Pictures"))

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Works like a charm!